Show inline error messages in VSCode + Robot Code
I run tests using Robot Code extension in VSCode.
When I just started, it showed me error message inline. Something like this (this is a random screenshot, that I found online, it just looks similar) 
At some point I got tired of these messages and managed to turn them off.
But now I want to get them back and I cannot find what setting was this. I even tried to delete settings.json file. But it didn't help.
Any ideas on what setting is there and how I can find it? Thanks!

The ideal would be to have more information about the error. Based on the data you've passed, you probably have a cache problem. Apparently Python is not finding the method implemented by some library you are using. Try running the following commands:
pip install --upgrade setuptools

After that, open Visual Studio code and perform the following action:

ctrl + shift + p -> In the search bar, search for "Clear caches and
restart Robot Framework Language Server".

I hope this solves your problem.
